# Word for someone who studies to become a teacher

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, translation, german

A friend of mine is currently writing her thesis in teaching methodology of mathematics. We are searching for an appropriate translation for the German word 'Lehramtsstudierender'. This is a person who is studying at university to become a teacher, but hasn't graduated yet. We found several expressions like 'student teacher', 'teacher student' and 'teacher trainee' and got the impression that a teacher trainee has already graduated. Is there a difference between a student teacher and a teacher student?

Comment: How about *teaching assistant*?

Comment: In the US the academic discipline is usually 'Education', so 'education student'.

Comment: I agree with *teaching assistant* (or *[post-]graduate teaching assistant*, if the person has got their first degree).

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan In Australia, the term *teaching assistant* refers to someone working in a classroom (to assist a teacher), not to a person studying to be a teacher. The person might be doing both, but the *assistant* title doesn't address the *student* part.

Comment: "Student teacher" was very common in US elementary and secondary schools until an increasing number of teacher-preparation programs sought to euphemize the apprenticeship with labels like "teaching intern" or "pre-professional."  (As an aside, I've had about 30 of them over the years, and changing the title hasn't made them any smarter...)

Comment: The term for someone studying to become a teacher is *student teacher*. A *teaching assistant* is as comparable as a *nurse* is to a *doctor*.

Comment: In the UK where a PGCE is the standard qualification for a secondary school teacher, "PGCE student" is common. I imagine something similar would work elsewhere.

Comment: *Trainee teacher* or *student teacher* are both clear descriptions to this UK English speaker of "... a person who is studying (at university) to become a teacher (but isn't yet qualified)".

Answer (score 2):

In Canada the term "education student" is used to describe a person taking courses at a university in a recognized program to become a teacher.  "Student teacher" is such a student during a practicum in a classroom.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt at university in a TESOL degree that we call ourselves pre-service teachers. Student teacher/teacher-student is someone who has started working in a school for the first time since qualifying as a teacher.

Comment: Does anyone else use the term "pre-service teachers"?

Comment: Yes, I have heard of "pre-service teachers".  In our university math department, this is used to describe math courses intended for those planning to become teachers.  This is in contrast to "in-service teachers" ... those already teaching,  but using the university to further their credentials.

Comment: In the UK, they were called "student-teachers." They were usually in their final year of an education degree at a college or university.

Answer (score -1):

teacher trainer is a person who teaches others to become teachers.

The student is called a trainee teacher or just trainee.

A student teacher is when the trainee actually steps into the classroom, is not yet a teacher and learns by doing.

Both in BrE and AmE.

[teacher trainer](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/cte/thinking-about-being-a-teacher/supporting-your-time-here/)

**teacher trainee**
[some training to become a teacher in AmE](https://www.twinkl.com/teaching-wiki/trainee-teacher#:%7E:text=A%20trainee%20teacher%20is%20someone,a%20degree%20in%20teaching%20education)

[https://www.twinkl.com/teaching-wiki/trainee-teacher#:~:text=A%20trainee%20teacher%20is%20someone,a%20degree%20in%20teaching%20education](https://www.twinkl.com/teaching-wiki/trainee-teacher#:%7E:text=A%20trainee%20teacher%20is%20someone,a%20degree%20in%20teaching%20education)

Comment: I've not heard this before in America and I know quite a few teachers and am married to a woman who was to start such a program this year but didn't.

Comment: Well, you better start googling then. It is completely AmE.

Comment: No need to be sassy. I didn't say you're wrong. Just adding information that it's maybe not that widespread.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- trainee teacher or teacher trainee